# MySQL subquery ERROR CODE 1241 SQLState 21000

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1241

I want to retrieve First and Last Row using client_id from my table. So I wrote this which threw an error (1241), Can Anyone please tell me what this issue with this code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices 
WHERE invoice_id IN (SELECT  MAX(invoice_id), 
                             MIN(invoice_id) 
                     FROM invoices
                     );
```

WHERE AS this code is perfectly fine :

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices 
WHERE invoice_id IN (SELECT  MIN(invoice_id) 
                     FROM invoices 
                     UNION SELECT MAX(invoice_id) 
                     FROM invoices
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

> So I wrote this which threw an error (1241), Can Anyone please tell me
> what this issue with this code :

The error `MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)` occurred because the following query

```
SELECT  MAX(invoice_id), MIN(invoice_id) FROM invoices
```

returns two columns, not two values. In the where condition you have one column declared `WHERE invoice_id IN`.